# Google vision OCR reader not able to detect small texts and inverted image.

Tags: android, ocr, android-camera2, google-vision

I have used Text Recognizer to extract text from image. I have used camera2 to capture image.

```
TextRecognizer textRecognizer = TextRecognizerController.getControllerInstance().getTextRecognizerInstance(getContext(), getView());
        if (textRecognizer != null && textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
            SparseArray<TextBlock> detectedItems = textRecognizer.detect(frame);

            if (detectedItems != null && detectedItems.size() != 0) {
                getPresenter().extractText(detectedItems);
            } else {
                displaySnackbar(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.Consult_MagicSearch_TextNotRecognizedErrorMessage));
            }
        } 



public void extractText(SparseArray<TextBlock> detectedItems) {
        TextBlock item = detectedItems.valueAt(0);
        String detectedText = item.getValue();
        contract.setTextRecognized(detectedText);
    }
```